# Using Spark ML's OneHotEncoder on multiple columns

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-ml

I've been able to create a pipeline that will allow me to index multiple string columns at once, but I am getting stuck encoding them, because unlike indexing, the encoder is not an estimator so I never call fit
according to the [OneHotEncoder example in the docs](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-features.html#onehotencoder).

```
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.{StringIndexer, VectorAssembler, 

OneHotEncoder}
import org.apache.spark.ml.Pipeline

val data = sqlContext.read.parquet("s3n://map2-test/forecaster/intermediate_data")

val df = data.select("win","bid_price","domain","size", "form_factor").na.drop()


//indexing columns
val stringColumns = Array("domain","size", "form_factor")
val index_transformers: Array[org.apache.spark.ml.PipelineStage] = stringColumns.map(
  cname => new StringIndexer()
    .setInputCol(cname)
    .setOutputCol(s"${cname}_index")
)

// Add the rest of your pipeline like VectorAssembler and algorithm
val index_pipeline = new Pipeline().setStages(index_transformers)
val index_model = index_pipeline.fit(df)
val df_indexed = index_model.transform(df)


//encoding columns
val indexColumns  = df_indexed.columns.filter(x => x contains "index")
val one_hot_encoders: Array[org.apache.spark.ml.PipelineStage] = indexColumns.map(
    cname => new OneHotEncoder()
     .setInputCol(cname)
     .setOutputCol(s"${cname}_vec")
)



val one_hot_pipeline = new Pipeline().setStages(one_hot_encoders)
val df_encoded = one_hot_pipeline.transform(df_indexed)
```

The OneHotEncoder object doesn't have a fit method so putting it in the same pipeline as the indexers will not work- it throws an error when I call fit on the pipeline.  I can also not call transform on the pipeline that I made with the array of pipeline stages, `one_hot_encoders`.

I have not found a good solution for using the OneHotEncoder without individually creating and calling transform on that transforming itself for all of the columns I want to encode

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Spark >= 3.0**:

In Spark 3.0 `OneHotEncoderEstimator` has been renamed to `OneHotEncoder`:

```
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.{OneHotEncoder, OneHotEncoderModel}

val encoder = new OneHotEncoder()
  .setInputCols(indexColumns)
  .setOutputCols(indexColumns map (name => s"${name}_vec"))
```

**Spark >= 2.3**

Spark 2.3 introduced new classes `OneHotEncoderEstimator`, `OneHotEncoderModel`, which required fitting even if used outside `Pipeline`, and operate on multiple columns at the same time.

```
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.{OneHotEncoderEstimator, OneHotEncoderModel}

val encoder = new OneHotEncoderEstimator()
  .setInputCols(indexColumns)
  .setOutputCols(indexColumns map (name => s"${name}_vec"))


encoder.fit(df_indexed).transform(df_indexed)
```

**Spark < 2.3**

Even if transformers you use don't require fitting you have to use `fit` method to create a `PipelineModel` which can be used to transform data.

```
one_hot_pipeline.fit(df_indexed).transform(df_indexed)
```

On a side note you can combine indexing and encoding into a single `Pipeline`:

```
val pipeline = new Pipeline()
  .setStages(index_transformers ++ one_hot_encoders)

val model = pipeline.fit(df)
model.transform(df)
```

**Edit**:

Error you see means that one of your columns contains an empty `String`. It is accepted by indexer but cannot be used for encoding. Depending on you requirements you can drop these or use a dummy label. Unfortunately you cannot use `NULLs` until [SPARK-11569)](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-11569) is resolved.

Comment: thanks - I updated the question here. I tried calling fit on the pipeline, but i think I might have set it up wrong.

Comment: also, maybe I am not entirely understanding the programming paradigm here/when things actually get run, but the reason I didn't put both index and encoder operations into the same pipeline is that the columns that I pass into the encoder instance don't exist before transform is called on the indexer.

Comment: Regarding error you see please check an edit. Combined pipeline will work just fine as long order reflects dependency graph (indexers go before encoder).

Comment: From the description of SPARK-11569, it looks like it only applies to PySpark, not the Scala API.

Comment: With a column of strings. Do you have to run `StringIndexer()` as well as `OneHotEncoderEstimator()`? Or can you just run the latter?